# Inversion method for generating random variates.

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose you have a cdf

$$
F(X)=\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3 + \frac{1}{2}      
$$

$$
0\leq x\leq 2
$$

How, would one find the inversion to create random variants?

I tried rearranging and inverting the equation into

$$
X=(2u-1)^\frac{1}{3}+1    
$$

$$
0\leq u\leq 1
$$

Graphing this inverted equation clearly only show half of the equation. I am not sure how to get the second half. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inverted the equation correctly. Unfortunately you didn’t show the graph you obtained that seemed to indicate a problem, so it’s hard to say what went wrong. Just in case you used Wolfram|Alpha to plot the inverse function, note that by default the principal root is used, which yields [this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%282u-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2B1%20for%20u%3D0..1&dataset=), but when you click on “Use the real-valued root instead” you get [this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%282u-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2B1%20for%20u%3D0..1&assumption=%22%5E%22%20-%3E%20%22Real%22), which is what you want for the inversion method.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, completely overlooked the imaginary solutions! I just graphed X=(2u−1)^1/3+1 on my graphics calculator and its clearly missing part of it. My main goal is to generate random variates with the inverse distribution to create the pdf in R. If I create U=runif(1000) and substitute into X=(2u−1)^1/3+1  some of the values are NaNs as they are imaginary as you pointed out. Im not sure how I would get R to  “Use the real-valued root instead”.

Comment: @Hilkjh: I don't use R myself, but I found [this manual page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/nthroot) which I believe should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much :D